# How to build an HTML table using a for loop in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to create a table on a webpage using python and flask. I have two lists, `testing_sketches` and `split_reconstructions`.

`testing_sketches`: It is a list of size 14, containing 14 image addresses.

`split_reconstructions`: It is a list of lists containing 14 lists of length 20. Basically, there are 20 image addresses corresponding to each of the 14 images in the previous list. This means it includes 20 image addresses for each image address in `testing_sketches`.

I am trying to iteratively take an image from `testing_sketches` and display its 20 images in `split_reconstructions` on its right. Something like the following:

[image]

And I have tried to implement it using the following code:

```
<body>        
    <h2 style="margin-left: 1.5%;">Iterative Reconstructions</h2>
    {% for i in range(len(testing_sketches)) %}
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3 style="margin-left: 10%;">{{ i+1 }}.</h3>
            <center><table border="1">
            <COLGROUP>
            <COL width="100"><COL width="100">
            <THEAD>
            <tr>
                <td><center><b>Image<b></center><a href={{  testing_sketches[i] }} title="Input" class="thickbox"><img src={{  testing_sketches[i] }} alt="Sorry, No Display!" border="0"/></a></td>
                {% for j in range(20) %}
                <td><center><b>Reconstruction-{{ j }}<b></center><a href={{  split_reconstructions[i][j] }} title="Reconstructed-{{ iter_count }}" class="thickbox"><img src={{  split_reconstructions[i][j] }} alt="Sorry, No Display!" border="0"/></a></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </table></center>
    {% endfor %}   
    
</body>
```

But this results in a blank result, no alternate display, no error, just an empty result. I have tried to check the length of the lists that I am passing on, and all of them are non-empty and have correct image addresses of the form: `static/test_reconstructions/images/image_04666_img.png` (an example of one of the addresses)

I pass the lists and the functions used in the `app.py` file as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():

    return render_template('iterative_reconst.html', testing_sketchs=testing_sketchs, split_reconstructions=split_reconstructions, 
    len=len, range=range)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want a table for each entry in the first list. This table shall have the number of columns corresponding to the entry in the respective second list, headed by the entry in the first list.

For this jinja2 provides the [filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) [`length`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.length) and [loop indices](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for). Your code would look something like this.

```
{% for sketch in testing_sketches %}
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Image</th>
    {% for i in range(split_reconstructions[loop.index0] | count) %}
    <th>Reconstruction-{{i+1}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </thead>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ sketch }}</td>
      {% for addr in split_reconstructions[loop.index0] %}
      <td>{{ addr }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, thank you for the answer, I will remember to use loops in Jinja like you have mentioned. But I had passed the functions `len` and `range` from my `app.py` flask file so that wasn't the problem I think(added that line of code in the question as well). Your code still results in the same output, no table is generated. I've been trying to see why that's happening and I've realised that nothing inside the for loop is being run. I don't know why that's happening even when the lists aren't empty.

Comment: I realised it was a silly typo between `sketches` and `sketchs`. Should I delete the question?

Comment: If you think you found the error on your own and the question doesn't help others, you can delete the question. Otherwise click the tick.